# Role mapping in tomcat

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, web, glassfish

So, when a web application gets deployed to my Container, I want to map 
those application specific roles to the user groups or just to single 
users which I have in my JDBCRealm.

For the glassfish Application Server, there seems to be a separate deployment
descriptor (glassfish-web.xml) for this reason:

```
<sun-web-app>
<context-root>/theapp</context-root>

    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        <principal-name>randy</principal-name>
        <principal-name>amanda</principal-name>
    </security-role-mapping>

    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
        <group-name>tomcatusergroup</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
<sun-web-app>
```

The role names there, are those from the web.xml security constraints, like

```
<security-role>
       <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
</security-role>
```

The `<principal-name>` is a user which is stored in my JDBCRealm, and the
 is a group of users there.

How can I establish this link/mapping in Tomcat?

Comment: I have exactly this question too! I was looking at an old GlassFish example and I really wish there was an answer for this one in Tomcat but it seems to be something a full enterprise container provides e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbxv/index.html